# Excel - hyperlink formula referencing cells on another worksheet increasing by 10 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hyperlink

In my workbook, I have two worksheets that I link information between - WS1 and WS2.

On **WS2** in column **A** - I have hyperlinks referring to specific cells in column **C** of **WS1**.

How do I write a hyperlink formula that can be copied down the column to the link references the cells on WS1 in increments of 10 rows?

So hyperlink in

- A2 on WS2 links to cell C3 on WS1
- A3 on WS2 links to C13 on WS1
- A4 on WS2 links to C23 on WS1

and so on...

I've been trying to use hyperlink with various combinations of row but haven't been able to figure out the right formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, enter the reference formula in the WS2 Worksheet A1 cell:

```
='WS1'!C1
```

[image]

Then enter the formula in WS2 Worksheet A2 cell:

```
=INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT($A$1),2,LEN(FORMULATEXT($A$1))-1-(LEN(FORMULATEXT($A$1))-FIND("C",FORMULATEXT($A$1))))&(NUMBERVALUE((RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($A$1),LEN(FORMULATEXT($A$1))-FIND("C",FORMULATEXT($A$1))))))*(ROW()-ROW($A$1))*10)
```

[image]

The WS1 Worksheet:

[image]

Comment: This gave me an error message.  I can't view the images right now but I'll look at them later.  Just looking at the formula, I don't think it's quite what I need.  I need to generate hyperlinks that will allow me to "jump" to the correct cell on the other worksheet.  Thank you very much for your response.